# 'Expected in: flat namespace' Rails error while db:reset in Apple M1 processor macOs BigSur 11.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, macos-big-sur

I've recently acquired a macOs BigSur, unfortunately, I have had a lot of issues trying to install a Rails App. After some days coming over issues with forum answers, I have encountered an issue that I cannot solve and there's not too much on the internet about how to solve this.

Whenever I run the following command `rails db:reset` I get the following output:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _grpc_set_ssl_roots_override_callback
  Referenced from: /Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.38.0/src/ruby/lib/grpc/grpc_c.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _grpc_set_ssl_roots_override_callback
  Referenced from: /Users/usr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.38.0/src/ruby/lib/grpc/grpc_c.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

zsh: abort      rails db:reset
```

I reviewed this Github issue https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24846 and followed the steps marked by nilleb user to solve my first issue, but then I got into this error message which is also mentioned in the same thread but I couldn't find a way to solve it.

When I run `gem list` I get

- grpc (1.38.0 ruby universal-darwin)
- google-protobuf (3.17.3 ruby universal-darwin)

And my ruby version is

- ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [-darwin20]

I read the posts made by the user premist but didn't know exactly what to do.

Could you please help me in this situation? I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The issue was caused by my homebrew path, and I needed to install its folder in /usr/local/homebrew instead of /usr/opt/homebrew because /opt/homebrew is for ARM use (so I had to install with intel).
I uninstalled brew and all its tools such as rbenv, nvm, etc. Then, I installed brew again but with the arch flag x86_64 command: `arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c \"$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)\"`. After this, I installed rbenv, nvm, and other tools always using arch flag: arch -x86_64